# AngularJS $scope update with two new object($scope) whose member functions update $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, javascript-objects

Fairly new to Angular and JS in general. After reading a lot about $scope in angular I am still at a loss with respect to the bug - please help! I have a controller which relies on two separate js functions, both of which take the $scope of the controller as an argument. I am clearly missing something with respect to how $scope is being updated here - the variable is updated once (delayed by one call, the first is null - if I set it explicitly within the newly constructed object, it never updates) and never again.

```
    //in the controller...

//have tried with and without this $watch, no dice. window pops with the correct value, 
//then the immediately pops again with the very first value entered since a new window  
var x;
$scope.$watch('bar.id', function(newval, oldval) {
      window.alert($scope.bar.id);
      x=newval;
    });

user = new userScript($scope, $http, $timeout, $user, socket,
        userId,
        'myForm', 'foo',
        '/api/user/show/' + userId, '/api/user/upsert/'+ userId,
        'userUnits');

unit = new unitScript($scope, $http, $timeout, $user, socket,
        userId,
        'myForm', 'bar', '/api/unit/upsert/' + null,
        'unitFields');

//unit.save() calls unit/upsert (uses $http.put) with a null argument, which creates a new record.
//it also sets $scope['bar'].id to the key of that new record.
//the intent is for the $watch to update that part of the scope, then
//save it (have tried this with/without $watch), then push that value onto 
//$scope.foo.units[], which is then upserted as userUnits[] in a call to user.save()  
$scope.newUnit = function(){
        unit.save();
        $scope.foo.units.push(x);
        user.save();
      }
```

//newUnit is called from an ng-click button element.

looking at the database, the array stored by the user looks like
userUnits[ null, firstId, firstId, firstId ....]

It seems like there are two conflicting versions of $scope here, one overwriting the other (commenting out user.save() does stop the overwrite, but prevents the upload of the data I want to save). I can't piece together exactly how they are interacting, however. I have tried using $apply to no avail as well. Thanks in advance for any time/advice!

Comment: Your understanding of what `$scope` is and how it is interacting with your code seems flawed, but your question and code in general is hard to follow.  can you update the question with the full declaration of your controller and HTML, and pull the expected and actual results out of comments so that it is more clear what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: for the record, angular creates many `scope` objects to facilitate two way bindings with the HTML; it doesn't belong to a controller.  `$scope` is a service which allows you to bridge your controller with the various HTML scopes, so without seeing what the HTML looks like, it's impossible to understand what `$scope` represents.

Comment: reading the code comments, it actually seems like this isn't an issue with `$scope` at all; rather an issue with the way that your two services are interacting with each other.

Comment: thank you for the response!
the HTML is fairly large - let me see if I can condense it...
there are several ng-model='bar.something.something'
encapsulated in one form of name "myform",
at the bottom of which is an ng-click='newUnit()'

Comment: so if you are binding to the `bar` object, what are you trying to push into the `foo` object?

Comment: bar.id, the key returned during an $http.put() request should but pushed to the foo.units array

Comment: I'm guessing that `unit.save()` is an async call (using `$http`)?  It sounds to me like you are taking the wrong path when dealing with `$http`; you probably just want to chain off the `$http.put()` with a `.then` function that pushes `bar.id` into `foo.units`; this whole use of `$watch` and some external variable isn't right, or necessary.

Comment: I think the question is probably more about async services than about `$scope`, and I also suspect that the behavior you are mentioning (window pops twice, with right value then wrong value) is directly related to how async functions are processed.

Comment: I'll try chaining the promises, thanks again!